# Kubernetes Role for cluster wide resources

Tags: kubernetes

As passing through k8s documentation I bumped into one thing that is quite unclear.

From the following [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole) we see that one of the main differences between Role and ClusterRole would be that in the ClusterRole you can specify access to cluster-wide resources (nodes, psp) while in the Role you cannot do that as those are namespaced scoped resources.

Now, i have bumped into lots of examples where some cluster-wide resources appears to be added in the Role manifest and it seems to work. Let's take the following example for PSP where from the api-resources we can see that these are non-namespaced resources.

```
kubectl api-resources | grep -i psp
podsecuritypolicies               psp          policy                         false        PodSecurityPolicy
```

Also, checking out the [psp k8s docs](https://v1-23.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/pod-security-policy/#via-rbac) we can see that both Role and ClusterRole can be created...

Same situation with nodes/certificatesigningrequests.
I have tested it out and deployed a service account, Role and RoleBinding and they throw:

```
Warning: resource 'nodes' is not namespace scoped
yes
```

Any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can not manage a resource that is not part of **any** namespace with inherently namespaced Role/RoleBinding. Those can only be managed by ClusterRole/ClusterRoleBindings